# How to find these check box elements in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, select, element

**I can't locate the check boxes [on this site](https://onecall.1100.com.au/au-b4-en/Account/Login) in Selenium**

I have tried: Xpath, ID, Type, Actionkeys, Text and partial text. I've been able to send keys (user and password) and locate the user / pass elements.

- **Code:**
- label for="acceptTermsAndConditions" class="checkbox-label-margin">
  -#I accept the Terms and Conditions
- xpath - //*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/label[1](https://onecall.1100.com.au/au-b4-en/Account/Login)

Thanks for your help in advance, I feel like I'm going around in circles.

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR see code with clarifying comments below.*

One of the reasons why it was not working for you could be that you needed to *wait for the form to get rendered, visible and interactable*. This could be solved with an [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Another problem that I've noticed with just clicking the "Accept Terms" via `.click()` was that, since the click happens in the middle of the element, it opens up Terms of Use in a separate tab which is undesirable. You could work this around by *clicking with an offset* of `(0, 0)` with [Action Chains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains).

As far as getting to the checkboxes with selenium locators, it could be done in a variety of different ways. In the code below, I am using *CSS selectors* while checking the value of `for` attributes of `label` elements.

The working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://onecall.1100.com.au/au-b4-en/Account/Login')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# wait for the form to get visible
login_form = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loginForm')))

# accept terms
accept_terms = login_form.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for=acceptTermsAndConditions]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(accept_terms, 0, 0).click().perform()

# keep me logged in
login_form.find_element_by_css_selector('label[for=checkbox2]').click()

# take a screenshot to prove it is working
login_form.screenshot('form.png')
```

And, this is what you are gonna see in `form.png`:

[image]